# Can BSOD be caused by corrup Windows 10 user profile?

Tags: windows-10, bsod

It was suggested to me by a support person from a well-known manufacturer that the 3 BSODs **during boot** and before login in the last month were caused by corrupt file or files in my user account. (The comment was made during a remote support session looking for defective hardware.) I am highly skeptical and would like to know if BSODs due to corrupt profiles is even possible?

FWIW, the system is a laptop less than a year old. Compared with my desktop system that's been used for software development for more than four years, very little has been loaded on it. It's used primarily for checking email and news before breakfast.

Comment: A corrupt profile could indeed be a possible cause for a BSOD.  However, if a corrupt profile is a cause, would entirely depend on the BSOD itself.

Comment: Last two BSODs: `DPC WATCHDOG VIOLATION`, `PFN LIST CORRUPT`. So it is true that profile corruption may cause BSOD before login?

Comment: You will have to use windbg and analyze the dump file to determine the cause of the BSOD in question.  There are multiple reasons you would receive a DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION

Comment: I understand there are multiple causes for most if not all BSODs and solving takes time. What I'm trying to figure out is whether the support tech was right or blowing smoke.

Comment: I am unable to conclude what might have been the case without specifics. I have indicated what must be supplied, the analysis from windbg, will provide that information

Comment: Usually windows will load a temporary user profile if your normal user profile is corrupt, it could be malware on the system causing the bsod.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the question was whether it was possible for a corrupt user profile to cause a BSOD during boot, the answer appears to be yes. The question was motivated by my concern whether a support tech was providing accurate information. That information thus appears to be correct.

Please note that the question was NOT whether a specific BSOD was caused by a corrupt user profile.